# Flutter. Why does the keyboard (focus) appear and immediately disappear when i click on the input?

Tags: flutter, dart

The question will be about the Flutter application.

There are two pages. On the first form with text inputs. On the second ListView.builder()

If i first open the page with the ListView, and then the page with the form. Then when i click on the input, the keyboard first appears for a moment and the focus and keyboard immediately disappear. And so it continues until the application is restarted.

But if i first open the form, then the inputs work fine.

What could be the problem?

P.S. Tried both unfocus() and wrapping the form or list in Focus, nothing helps!

Video of problem:
https://www.veed.io/view/24122e64-e6a4-430f-a914-4e25a62f1959?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

ListView:
If I remove the list from the second page, then the form on the first page working correctly anyway

```
_controller = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: _leftPadding);

ListView.builder(
  controller: _controller,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: null,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     /// Some code here thats returned Container() 
  }
);
```

Form and TextField without any controllers:

```
Form(key: formKey, child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
       TextFormField(
         minLines: 10,
         maxLines: 15,
         keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
         textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
         validator: validator,
         /// Simple TextFormField only with validator
       )
    ]
));
```

Comment: Please add your code sample

Comment: @Eternity Added sample code

Comment: Can I have the code sample for the first page as well? Do you have some kind of controller for the TextField?

Comment: @EverydayEngineer No, TextField without controllers

Comment: I still cannot see anything wrong from the code snippets you include. Are you navigating to page 2 and back? This behavior can happen if the Form widget is redrawn. Does your ListView somehow impact the form?

Comment: @EverydayEngineer No, the ListView does not affect the form. And the fact is that it is after the list is deleted that the form starts working. But I don't know what is causing this behavior.

Comment: @MrFavour I had the same problem before. How many `MaterialApp` widgets do you have?

Comment: The `formKey` how is it defined and how many views is making use of it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.